# Using find method of org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils with Predicate

Tags: collections, apache-commons

I was using `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils` and for this version using find method was like this:

```
BeanPropertyValueEqualsPredicate objIdEqualsPredicate = new BeanPropertyValueEqualsPredicate("objId", objId);
myObj = (MyClass) CollectionUtils.find(myObjSet, objIdEqualsPredicate);
```

But with `org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils`, I don't know how to make it work.
Here what I do now but if there is a clear way of it, I will be glad to learn:

```
Predicate<MyClass> objIdEqualsPredicate = new Predicate<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(MyClass obj) {
        return obj.getObjId().equals(objId);
    }
};
myObj = CollectionUtils.find(myObjSet, objIdEqualsPredicate);
```

Is there a way to filter some objects according to the their fields' values. If possible I don't want to use anonymous class for this.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? `CollectionUtils` still has a `find` method on it. Show us what you tried already. And on't be afraid of anonymous inner classes, that's what they're there for.

Comment: @skaffman I've added the details about the new one.

Answer (score 0):

As the common-beanutils still have commons-collections as dependency, you must implement the Predicate interface.

For example you can take the source code of `BeanPropertyValueEqualsPredicate` and refactor it, so your version implements the `org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate` interface.

Or you write your own version. I would prefer not to use anonymous inner classes, because of the possibility to write unit tests for the predicate and reuse it.

Quick Example (not nullsafe,..)

```
@Test
public class CollectionsTest {

@Test
void test() {

    Collection<Bean> col = new ArrayList<>();
    col.add(new Bean("Foo"));
    col.add(new Bean("Bar"));

    Predicate<Bean> p = new FooPredicate("Bar");

    Bean find = CollectionUtils.find(col, p);
    Assert.assertNotNull(find);
    Assert.assertEquals(find.getFoo(), "Bar");

}

private static final class FooPredicate implements Predicate<CollectionsTest.Bean> {

    private String fieldValue;

    public FooPredicate(final String fieldValue) {

        super();
        this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(final Bean object) {

        // return true for a match - false otherwise
        return object.getFoo().equals(fieldValue);
    }
}

public static class Bean {

    private final String foo;

    Bean(final String foo) {

        super();
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getFoo() {

        return foo;
    }
}
}
```